# PHP Warning: ftp_fput(): Can't open that file: Is a directory in

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file to FTP.

Here is my code:

```
$connect = ftp_connect('ftp.my-server.fr');
$login = ftp_login($connect, 'username', 'pass');

$remote_file = '/' . $date;
$local_file = fopen('C:/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/myfolder/' . $hour .'.mp3', 'r');

ftp_chdir($connect, '/'.$date);

if (ftp_fput($connect, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "The file $local_file has been loaded";
} else {
    echo "Error while uploading file " . $local_file;
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> PHP Warning:  ftp_fput(): Can't open that file: Is a directory in C:\MAMP\htdocs\mysite\index.php on line 26

I don't understand because the path is the file. When I paste `$local_file` URL in my browser the sound is playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$local_file` is OK, but your `$remote_file` is a directory (you use `'/' . $date` for `ftp_chdir`), and it need to be a path to a file (that will be created)

You can copy the same filename than the local file with `basename` :

```
$remote_dir = '/' . $date;
$local_file = fopen('C:/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/myfolder/' . $hour .'.mp3', 'r');

ftp_chdir($connect, $remote_dir);
$remote_file = $remote_dir . '/' . basename($local_file) ;

if (ftp_fput($connect, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "The file $local_file has been loaded";
} else {
     echo "Error while uploading file " . $local_file;
}
```